# Way to view primary monitor from secondary

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

Setup:

> Windows 7 x64
>
> Dual monitors
>
> Primary monitor is used for most programs
>
> > Primary is also used for TV, and a game console.
>
> Secondary monitor is used for music, skype, email, etc..

When I want to use my computer while watching TV I usually have to end up switching inputs and dragging any programs that open up on the primary display over to my secondary.

Are there any programs out there that would let me view/pan to the primary display without messing up icon locations?

Or even a quick way to swap what's on primary and secondary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enable and disable your second monitor with the shortcut: Win + P. There are few options like main monitor, mirror, extend and second monitor only.

If you want to be swapping this monitor, I think it should not be your primary.